# Multiple inputs in C

Tags: c

Just starting to learn C/C++ in my CS 221 class.

Here's the start of my code:

```
int main()
{
    int id;
    char name[100];
    double wages;

    printf("Enter employee's id: ");
    scanf("%4i", id);
    printf("Enter employee's full name: ");
    scanf("%99[^\n]",name);
    printf("Enter gross salary for %s :",name);

    return 0;
}
```

Having trouble wrapping my head around char arrays, stdin and buffers in c. Why does the above code skip the user imputing a name?  do I need fflush in there? couldn't really get that to work either.

Comment: make it `scanf(" %99[^\n]",name);`, leading space is to consume`'\n'`

Comment: `scanf("%4i", id);` -> `scanf("%4i", &id);`

Comment: `int id; ... scanf("%4i", id);` --> enable all compiler warnings.

Comment: `scanf` should never be used by beginners, as it will only confuse you.  (It should never be used by anyone, but that's a different issue)

Comment: Thanks! Both of your answers helped a lot.  One final thing: code works good now as long as you don't enter too many digits for the first input.  Why would that be?

Comment: @WilliamPursell Why not?

Comment: What would you suggest as a good replacement for it @WilliamPursell?

Comment: There is no such thing as "C/C++". Continue with your class at your own risk.

Comment: @WilliamPursell C should never be used by beginners. Here, FTFY.

Comment: @J...S Because `scanf` itself implements its own language that confuses the neophyte.  As a replacement, @Cherubim, I recommend that beginners use `fread`, `fgets`, `fgetc`, and `getchar`.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure why you use

```
scanf("%4i", id);
```

But try:

```
scanf("%d", &id );
```

This fixes the issue of `%4i` format, and replaces it with `%d` for "Decimal integer" format.

This also fixes the issue of `, id);` because written like this, will not allow id to be stored, and would definitely crash.

If you have issues with numbers you are entering crashing from being too big, maybe check the boundaries of your data type `int` which will be platform specific.

Also change:

```
scanf("%99[^\n]",name);
```

to:

```
scanf("%s\n",name);
```

This takes the data entered by the user through scanf and interprets it as a "String of characters" and places it in `name` properly.